# Android, Java cannot read process output/error streams

Tags: java, android, python

I have, wrapped a static compiled python in my android project, and then executed a python script(webserver), program is running fine, but i cannot read the output/error stream, so that i have executed `python3.4 -h` which is reading fine by the program.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine, envp,cwd);
readStream(process.getInputStream());
readStream(process.getErrorStream());
process.waitFor();
```

`readStream()` opens a new thread, what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with python's bufferd stdout and stderr, i just added `python3.4 -u` to solve the issue, 
Refer
[How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)